# Update PostGIS extensions on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, postgis

Everything worked fine, but some time ago rails app response a error.

***PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR: could not access file “$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory***

Also now I can't create database backup, it's crashed on table which working whit postgis. Backup will creating if exclude this table.

pg:psql -c "\dx  postgis"

*postgis 2.1.7*

I tried to find a solution to this problem and what I found was:

*ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;*

*ALTER EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal UPDATE;*

*ALTER EXTENSION postgis_topology UPDATE;*

*ALTER EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder UPDATE;*

But have error on this command *ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;*

***ERROR:  cannot create temporary table within security-restricted operation***

As I understand it, during work command will creating temp table. But in our case we have not permissions to create temp table for user whom was given for me by Heroku postgres.

What solution for this problem have?

Comment: Support team of Heroku helped me.

Comment: and how did they help ? Might be helpful to others with the same issue.

Comment: They  **Update REDIS by heroku-redis**, this appeared in activity tab on dashboard. Why it was Redis, I don't know... It surprised me.