# Issue with Heoku Postgres "could not access file “$libdir/postgis-2.1"

Tags: django, heroku, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I have a project that works with GeoDjango, Postgis and its deploy it in Heroku.

Some info of what I'm using:

- Python 2.7.15
- Django 1.11.20
- Heroku-18 (Stack)
- Postgres 9.4.20
- Postgis 2.1.8

In the last months the system threw me an error every time I want to load de geografic info, when I execute a geocode query.

> ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or
>   directory

I have looked for the web and stackoverflow for the solutions and I found some that was really near of my problem but I tried their solutions and doesn't work for me.

I tried the "`ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE`" solution but throw me this error:

> ERROR:  cannot create temporary table within security-restricted
>   operation

I tried the "*backup your DB, Drop the local database and restaurations*" but when I run the comand `pg:backups:capture` I get

> An error occurred and the backup did not finish.

When I run the `pg:backups:info`
And trow me this:

> 2019-03-02 23:08:31 +0000 pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed:
>   ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or
>   directory   ... (some database code)   2019-03-02 23:08:31 +0000
>   waiting for pg_dump to complete   2019-03-02 23:08:31 +0000 pg_dump
>   finished with errors

Then I found this entry 
[Update PostGIS extensions on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213361/update-postgis-extensions-on-heroku)
And found that it's the same problem that I have with heroku postgres, (but the author is using ruby) and the author says that was helped by the support team of Heroku. Well I create a ticket and find that "*Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community*" and stackoverflow, so I tried to add a comment to this user to say samething like "hey, can you share the solution please? I have the same problem." but I haven't enough reputation to do it.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution !!!**

With an old db backup archive that I had, I reset the db from the heroku datastores section and after that I restored with the backup archive (with pgAdmin III) and the problem its gonne.

Its seems like the error was with postgis version, becouse when I had the problem my postgis version was **2.1.8** and now with the error solved my versión of postgis is **2.4.4**.

I hope it is useful to someone.